# Selecting a piece of text using QTextCursor

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtextcursor

Having problems with selecting pieces of text using the Qt framework. For example  if i have this document : "No time for rest". And i want to select "ime for r" and delete this piece of text from the document, how should i do it using QTextCursor? Here is my code:

```
QTextCursor *cursor = new QTextCursor(ui->plainTextEdit->document());
cursor->setPosition(StartPos,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor->setPosition(EndPos,QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
cursor->select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
cursor->clearSelection();
```

Unfortunately it deletes the whole line from the text. I've tried using other selection types like  WordUnderCursor or BlockUnderCursor, but no result. Or maybe there is a better way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. `cursor->select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);` line selects whole current line. You don't want to delete whole line, so why would you write this? Remove this line of code.
2. `clearSelection()` just deselects everything. Use `removeSelectedText()` instead.
3. Don't create `QTextCursor` using `new`. It's correct but not needed. You should avoid pointers when possible. `QTextCursor` is usually passed by value or reference. Also you can use `QPlainTextEdit::textCursor` to get a copy of the edit cursor.

So, the code should look like that:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor();
cursor.setPosition(StartPos, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor.setPosition(EndPos, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
cursor.removeSelectedText();
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot. I am new to Qt, and thre is a lot to learn here.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp I forgot to delete those values from test code. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the selection as opposed to the characters based on your desire.

Please read the documentation of the method:

> [void QTextCursor::clearSelection()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#clearSelection)
>
> Clears the current selection by setting the anchor to the cursor position.
>
> Note that it does **not** delete the text of the selection.

You can see that it only deleted the selection, not the text. Please use the following method instead:

> void QTextCursor::removeSelectedText()
>
> If there is a selection, its content is deleted; otherwise does nothing.

Having discussed the theory, let us demonstrate what you could write:

```
QTextCursor *cursor = new QTextCursor(ui->plainTextEdit->document());
cursor->setPosition(StartPos,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor->setPosition(EndPos,QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
// If any, this should be block selection
cursor->select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
cursor->removeSelectedText();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```